# "Connection Reset", "No data recieved" all of the time on my website

Tags: godaddy, ajax, error

I'm building an imageboard, and for some reason this error happens all of the time (ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE).

[image]

I talked to GoDaddy and they say everything seems fine on their side.

Let's say you are **trying** to create this problem from my perspective, what would you do? What can make this happen? And how do I prevent it.

The "ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE"s usually last about 1-2 minutes, and when I'm at my school and a couple of friends and I are on my website we all get it.

The funny thing is that say **I get the error**, then I still see my friends on the website on their computers. Then later on **they get the error** although I can still browse it....

I use quite a bit of Ajax, might this be the problem? I also tried clearing my .htaccess, still not helping.

Comment: What is `ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE`? Does your code return it? Does it appear to be a server response?

Comment: @JohnConde - It's a Chrome response. http://i.imgur.com/jnURLnH.png - Firefox returns "Connection Reset"

Comment: Neither of these are server errors so there is nothing to fix on the server I assume. These are more network errors. If this happens at school but not at home, then you can narrow it down the network at school. If you get this at home and at the local coffee shop too, then I would not be blaming the local network but looking somewhere up-stream. This may be hard to trace. One thing you can do is create a fairly reasonably sized (semi-loaded) static page that can be accessed. If this works consistently while getting errors, then I would be looking at the site again.

Comment: @closetnoc I'm afraid it happens on various different internet connections, all that I've tried. Also, when I get the error, no page on the domain is available for atleast one minute before the error goes away...

Comment: Try a sizable static page during this time. It can be a junk page. You do not have to link it. Just make sure you know what it should look like. This will tell you if it is the server or the site/page.

Comment: Make sure the page is fairly large. The reason for this is for the page to take some time to download. Think War and Peace. But make it just plain ole HTML and do not use a CMS or other software. Just a a simple HTML page. If you have issues accessing the page, it has nothing to do with your code. It will be the web server, the network or something.

Comment: @closetnoc I think I understand what you mean. I made one with 2k lines with long paragraphs as well as a couple of forms and stuff from html-ipsum. Now what? Is the point only to see if I can load it? Because the error only occurs sometimes, quite randomly in my experience. EDIT: The page loaded just fine (http://vikingchan.org/large.html)

Comment: Yep! That is exactly right. When the error occurs, immediately try the long HTML file and back and forth. Have a few people do this too if you can. The idea is to isolate whether it is a web server/network issue or a page code issue. I have used this technique since the beginning of the web to isolate where to begin looking for an error. It is a handy trick!! ;-) Simple too. If you can load this long page just fine when your other page errors, then it has to be a code issue.

Comment: @closetnoc Awesome! That's really interesting. I will definitely try this out and report back

Comment: @closetnoc Looks like a code issue! The page loads just fine. Any idea what kind of code might trigger this? The homepage won't load as well so I guess that gives me a lead on which files the index shares with the boards.

Comment: Seems like the only thing they share is the connection file really... Strange. Might it have something to do with that? Or session_start? Maybe setting the charset in the DB? I have no clue

Comment: I do not know. For the sake of getting an answer, what CMS or other software are you using? Are you "rolling your own"? I do not know AJAX even though I will need to start using it myself, but how do you use AJAX (code methods)? I suggest updating the question. But now you know where to look.

Comment: I do not know where to begin looking. Sorry. Can you find scenarios on your site where this works consistently? Sometimes comparing stable code to unstable code really helps narrow down where to look. I wish I knew AJAX more. I know that it is simple, but there are gotchas that are discovered and avoided with experience.

Comment: @closetnoc I honestly don't know much of it either. I just learned to fetch and send data so that I could have automated systems instead of having to reload all of the time. I'm not using an CMS unfortunately (in this case), but I guess I'll just have to take the time and narrow it down like you are suggesting. Thanks for the help though!

Comment: Anytime! I will see if I can find some solid information that may help. Also, I will see if there is something that can be done to get more attention to this question.

Comment: The only thing I can suggest immediately is if there are any clues in your web server access and error log files? As well, perhaps checking the slow query log in your database. MySQL has one and I am assuming others do too. You might have to turn this on for a while, though I do not suggest leaving it on too long. Otherwise, perhaps there are clues in your database log too for queries that are not completing for some reason. I know slow queries can really effect web stuff and are often simple to fix with additional indexes or re-ordering the SQL query.

Comment: @closetnoc Okay this is strange. I noticed I misspelled `if($db->connect_error > 0){` to `connect_errno` . Now whenever the posts stop loading, it doesn't make the whole website go down. Still a problem, but a very much smaller one. I hope this isn't just random after I fixed the code.

Comment: @JohnConde I know the system will give more attention to questions, but is there anything else that can be done to help the OP?? It appears to be a server side issue.

Comment: @closetnoc Nevermind it was random.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20485/discussion-between-schart-and-closetnoc).

Comment: Yeah. I know that sometimes I fat finger things and these are hard to find. I have an issue with an in-line process that goes wonky myself. It appears to be random and database load based. I am cleaning things up to cut down the number of connections and queries. As well, if any connection or query fails, I am adding more graceful code. It should have simply ignored and died gracefully- but it does not always and goes into a weird loop where there is not one. My error rate is about 12 out of 70,000 so it gets hard to trace.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Many people appear to have this problem on Godaddy hosting](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=err_empty_response%20godaddy) and Godaddy have told one complainant this

> It is possible that when the error is occurring that it is triggering
>   the Mod_sec of the hosting account. In the current hosting account
>   type that you have it isn't possible for us to disable that function
>   for security reasons. We do have hosting accounts with cPanel that
>   allow us to bypass the Mod_Sec rules, which could resolve the issue.

http://vanillaforums.org/discussion/27446/server-fails-every-once-in-a-while

Comment: So what exactly should I do? I have already tried their phone support, should I call again?

Comment: Personally speaking - I would move hosting and be done with it.

Answer (score 0):

Some more anecdotal info for future readers:

I created an AJAX-powered app which scrapes data from a 3rd party external site using a rapid-fire series of http requests.  This is done with PHP, using AngularJS on the frontend.  It works great on my local PC and it makes over 1000 requests pretty quickly and without error.

- When I upload the app to GoDaddy, I can see that after about 18-35 successful requests (it varies), they all begin to error out with `net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE`.  The whole domain hangs for a bit as described by OP.  Then I can try again and I get the exact same behavior.

This leads me to believe that GoDaddy has a bandwidth-per-minute cap or something of that nature.  I would be curious if OP's imageboard also loads a large amount of data or uses multiple rapid http requests.